# I tried to create music player in kivymd but its not working

Tags: kivy, kivymd

It's not getting the path of the when I run it.
It says b'Resource not found.' and    b'GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.'

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import os

helper_string = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: scroll

"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.sound = None
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:/music/'):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                    required_file = file
                    the_location = os.path.abspath(required_file)
                    self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=required_file, on_release=self.play_song))
                    

    
    def play_song(self, onelinelistitem):
        the_song_path = onelinelistitem.text
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.stop()
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(the_song_path)
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.play()
        print(the_song_path)

    

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `os.path.abspath()` returns an absolute version of the provided path, but it can't know what folder that path is in. It actually assumes that the provided path is in the current working directory. To get the correct path, change:

```
the_location = os.path.abspath(required_file)
self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=required_file, on_release=self.play_song))
```

to:

```
the_location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, required_file))
self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=the_location, on_release=self.play_song))
```

With that change, your code should work.